# Can't access my Opencart admin panel

Tags: authentication, opencart

I can't access my Opencart admin panel for my website. I made some changes (change the .htaccess.txt to .htaccess, add robotx.txt and add xml site map into the root folder)

Usually, my admin URL looked like [.....com/admin], now after trying to log in, it changes to [...com/admin/index.php?route=common/login]

Basically what I did in the htaccess was - avoiding my dublicate content and try to turn on the rewrite engine.

PLEASE HELP me with some advice,

Thank you.

Comment: Posting Your `.htaccess` file here would be as appreciated as our possible help then.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your session.php file is not configured correctly.

It is in `../system/library/session.php` and your code should read:

```
<?php
class Session {
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {     
        if (!session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');

            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
            session_start();
        }

        $this->data =& $_SESSION;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very funny for me (hope not for you). I got the same problem again and again the second day after installing OpenCart. Tried all found online but still can not login. Then I remember on top of Admin page, having Profile with another name and changed that to may name. That change my Admin Username also automatically!!! I try to use my name (no space between First and Last name) as Admin username... It  works!